# Azure App Service Deploy fails: '<app-service-name>' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I have already deployed my app in App Service for Container through Azure Devops "Azure App Service Deploy" Release task. Sometimes It finalizes right but mostly of times it fails showing the following error:

> 2022-02-03T08:57:29.8296464Z ##[error]Error: Resource 'app1'
> doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment.
> 2022-02-03T08:57:29.8312067Z (node:1938)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'getApplicationURL' of undefined.

For the record, I have two app services in the same app service plan (app1 and app2).  First time I deployed app1 and app2 there wasn't problem. After app2 was deployed, when I try to deploy app1 again the pipeline fails showing "Azure App Service Deploy fails: 'app1' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment", how ever I can check in Azure Portal that it does exist. After 10-20mins I try to deploty app1 again and it works. After that, I try to deploy app2 and it fails with the same error related to app2: "Azure App Service Deploy fails: 'app2' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment".

I cannot understand what the problem is, maybe some conflict because they are in the same app service plan, a bug in Azure Devops Azure App Service Deploy task, maybe I should destoy azure resources and re-create them...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi Ángel Martin, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what is causing the problems you're getting, but I can assure you that it's absolutely standard to have more than one app service in an app service plan, and that (in itself) should not cause any conflict.

Comment: I can also tell you that in my company we deploy multiple app services in the same plan using the [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) task, in whatever order, and they're absolutely fine.

Comment: A recommendation: examine your resource group's deployment history and activity log, for clues about app services being created and deleted.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74489130/1420841

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the app service is genuinely being removed?

For example if you have an ARM template which defines one app service plan and only one app service, which you first to deploy app1 and then to deploy app2 by giving it different parameters the second time; if you are deploying that template in [Complete mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes), it will actually delete any other app services which aren't listed in the arm template, so the second deployment would delete the first app service.

Comment: I'm using Terraform to create resoruces, 1 App Service Plan and 2 App Servces in that plan. I could check that is right in Azure Portal. I just run infrastructure pipelines once so I think it's not removing when I deploy my web app.